change the color of RSI retroactively when a condition is met
I want to write a custom RSI and change the color of the RSI line retroactively when my custom condition becomes true.
I managed to mark two points in the RSI, but I want to change the color between the two point to red for example. The idea is when the RSI moves 20 point or more, I want to change the color.
I need to re-color the previous bars too. Let's say, RSI starts going down at bar_index = 20. The downtrend moves 20 point at bar_index = 25. At that point only I get to know that it moved 20 points. I need to re-color the RSI from bar_index = 20 to bar_index = 25 too.
Here is my code so far:
//@version=5
indicator(title="Custom RSI Retrospective Coloring", overlay=false, format=format.price, precision=2)

// RSI kiszámítása
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input.source(close, "Source")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

// RSI szintvonalak
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=color.new(#434651, 0))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=color.new(#434651, 0))
band3 = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#434651, 50))
fill(band1, band0, color=color.new(#727171, 90), title="Background")

// Változók az RSI trend és csúcsok tárolására
var bool downRSITrend = false  // RSI is going down
var float downTrendKStartRSI = na  // Down trend started
var int downTrendStartBarIndex = na  // Down trend started bar index
var int downTrendEndBarIndex = na  // Down trend ends bar index

var label labelHi = na
var label labelLow = na

if rsi[1] > rsi[2] and rsi[0] < rsi[1]
    downRSITrend := true
    downTrendKStartRSI := rsi[1]
    downTrendStartBarIndex := bar_index[1]  

if downRSITrend and rsi[1] < rsi[2] and rsi[0] > rsi[1]
    downRSITrend := false
    if downTrendKStartRSI - rsi[1] >= 20  // when RSI moved at least 20 points
        downTrendEndBarIndex := bar_index[1]  
        labelHi := label.new( downTrendStartBarIndex, y=downTrendKStartRSI, style=label.style_circle, color=color.new(#eb2f1673, 55), size=size.tiny)
        labelLow := label.new( bar_index[0]-1, y=rsi[1], style=label.style_circle, color=#eb2f1673, size=size.tiny)

// to do: change the color to red somehow between downTrendStartBarIndex and downTrendEndBarIndex
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#425c70, linewidth=2)

I tried with the help of ChatGPT, but it didn't work.

Make the plotting color a variable:
var currentColor = <neutral color>
var neutralColor = <neutral color>
var downTrendStartColor = <start of down trend color, bright red maybe>
var downTrendColor = <color while in down trend, red maybe>
var downTrendEndColor = <Color on the end of a down trend, dark red maybe>

if rsi[1] > rsi[2] and rsi[0] < rsi[1]
    downRSITrend := true
--> currentColor = downTrendStartColor
    downTrendKStartRSI := rsi[1]
    downTrendStartBarIndex := bar_index[1]

if downRSITrend and rsi[1] < rsi[2] and rsi[0] > rsi[1]
    downRSITrend := false
--> currentColor = downTrendEndColor
    if downTrendKStartRSI - rsi[1] >= 20  // when RSI moved at least 20 points
        downTrendEndBarIndex := bar_index[1]  
        labelHi := label.new( downTrendStartBarIndex, y=downTrendKStartRSI, style=label.style_circle, color=color.new(#eb2f1673, 55), size=size.tiny)
        labelLow := label.new( bar_index[0]-1, y=rsi[1], style=label.style_circle, color=#eb2f1673, size=size.tiny)

if <inside down trend condition>
        currentColor = downTrendColor
        ...logic

else
    currentColor = neutralColor

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=currentColor, linewidth=2)


Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it's not what I need. At the start of a down trend, I don't know if it's going to be at least 20 point long, so I can't start coloring at that point. I need to change the color only after it went at least 20 point down from the starting point. In that case, I need to change the color for the previous RSI values starting from the downTrendEndBarIndex. I know how to keep the "red" color after that, what I don't know is how to change the color retroactively.

Oh, well in that case you can use
barcolor(color, offset, editable, show_last, title, display)
with a negative offset
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_barcolor
when the condition has met (in your case - when the change was atleast 20 points long)

barcolor is to color the price bars, I want to change the color of the RSI

there is similar question with a good and simpel answer here on SE: link

thanks, but that's as well coloring only starting with the current bar. I need to re-color the previous bars too. Let's say, RSI start going down at bar_index = 20. The downtrend moves 20 point at bar_index = 25. At that point only I get to know that it moved 20 points. I need to color the RSI from bar_index = 20 to bar_index = 25 too.
